# MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync() throws No overload for method 'LoginAsync' takes 1 arguments error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services, win-universal-app

I'm trying to put some common code (like user login) into a Class library (Portable for Universal Apps) project instead of the standard Blank Universal Apps project.

Unfortunately I can't build the class library, because this code snippet throws an error:

```
No overload for method 'LoginAsync' takes 1 arguments
```

code:

```
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Mobile.Common
    {
        public class UserHandler
        {
            /// ... properties, etc...                

            public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider provider)
            {                   
               this.currentUser = await MobileService.LoginAsync(provider); //error occurs here
               /// other code goes here...

             }
        }
}
```

I installed Azure Mobile Services Nuget package for my Class library project.
Based on the following forum, it is clear to me, that inside a Win8.1 or WinPhone8.1 this code works fine: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/720f607d-ad28-4d6b-b5e1-54145b243206/mobile-service-authentication?forum=azuremobile

But I don't know how to fix it in my class library project. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LoginAsync() method you are calling, is a platform specific method defined as an extension to the client in the platform specific dll, and as such is not usable from a PCL.

If you look at the PCL version of the MobileServiceClient, you will notice that it only supports logins where you already have the token from the identity provider.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/MobileServiceClient.cs

And here is how Windows Store adds in the server based auth UI for Win Store (using the Windows Auth Broker)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WindowsStore/Extensions/MobileServiceClientExtensions.cs

Comment: So I always have to put login stuff into the Shared (orWinPhone8.1 / Win8.1) project and there is no option to organize the login part into a class library. Is that correct?

Comment: You may be able to look at using the Windows Auth Broker directly, if you only need WP8.1 & Windows 8.1.  I'm not sure if its entirely PCL compliant either though.